# problem with generating rand number between 0 and 1 using C language

Tags: c

I am trying to generate some numbers with the rand() function like below:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
    printf("%f\n",rand_md());
    }
    return 0;
}



float rand_md()
{
    return (float)rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}
```

But when I run gcc rand.c, I get the error like below:
rand.c: In function ‘main’:
rand.c:21: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
rand.c: At top level:
rand.c:36: error: conflicting types for ‘rand_md’
rand.c:21: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘rand_md’ was here

What's wrong with my code?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a function without declaring it first, C will assume it returns an `int`. To fix this, you have to declare the method signature for `rand_md` before you call it in `main()`.

Add something like this before `main` or in a header file:

```
float rand_md();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double rand_md()
{
    return (double )rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}
```

Now, `rand_md` returns a `double` instead of a `float`.

Also, since you haven't included it in your post, you should throw in a function prototype before `main()`. You also forgot to add a semicolon to `int i = 0`. The corrected code looks like this:

```
double rand_md();    

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
    printf("%f\n",rand_md());
    }
    return 0;
}

double rand_md()
{
    return (double )rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use random(largest size of number) for this purpose.